# Django queryset get names of model fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to get field names of `Django` model through `queryset`.

Models.py:

```
class User1(models.Model):
    types1 = (
        ('a', 'a'),
        ('b', 'b'),
        ('c', 'c'),
    )
    types2 = (
        ('a', 'a'),
        ('b', 'b'),
        ('c', 'c'),
    )
    q1 = models.CharField (
        'Today1',
        max_length=200,
        choices=types1, blank=True, null=True, default='---------'
    )
    q2 = models.CharField (
        'Today2',
        max_length=200,
        choices=types2, blank=True, null=False, default='---------',
    )
```

After `queryset`, I want to get `[q1,q2]` or something similar to this but containing only field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
[f.name for f in User1._meta.get_fields()]
['id', 'q1', 'q2']
```